# should I use old software on on old hardware?

Tags: linux, updates

I have an old laptop (10 years)on which I am running Ubuntu mate 16.04.But I didn't get Latest gcc compilers on it.thus I want to upgrade to 17.04.so my question in cleare and it is

**should I use old software on on old hardware?**

Comment: It's not clear as you actually want to run a current build of a piece of software on an old piece of hardware. But there really isn't much of a relation. There are cases where it would make sense to use old hardware with old software but they're rather are in normal everyday use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unless the old hardware is no longer supported by the new software or recent releases of the software have grown too big (RAM and disk size, CPU speed).